# how to insert the value having double quotes in the database?

Tags: php, sql, insert, quoted-identifier

```
insert into sent_message (user_id,subject,message,background_url,total_recipients,created_at) values ('115','Greeting','Hx z'xi','/images/default/1.jpg',2,'2015-07-23 10:48:41')
```

For the message column i have used the value with single quotes hence i got the insertion error....

And i tried to change the query as below but the output and the error is same. Ho to over come it.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO insert into sent_message (user_id,subject,message,background_url,total_recipients,created_at) values ('115','Greeting','Hx z'xi','/images/default/1.jpg',2,'2015-07-23 10:48:41')
```

Comment: `addslashes` may help or escape the strings.

Comment: i want even single quotes to be inserted in the table.

Comment: to use *mysqli_real_escape_string()* is the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using prepared statements? This way you don't have to worry about adding the quotes in the values section; you use question marks instead as place holders.

You could then use `addslashes` to escape any double/single quotes when you pass your variables/strings to the execute method.

You didn't mention which database you're using, so I'm assuming MySQL?

Here is the PHP manual on prepared statements:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

The escape character for single quote (') is two single quotes (''). Thus
Example:

```
Insert into SomeTable(TextField) Select 'Some ''single quotes inserted'''
```

Will yield:

```
Select TextField from SomeTable

Some 'single quotes inserted'
```